# Error 500 in a ASP.NET MVC Application running on IIS 5 + Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, windows-server-2003, iis-5

My page has an Ajax.BeginForm helper and when I submit this form, in localhost, I have success but, when I run the same page and try to submit my page on the server (Windows Server 2003 + IIS 5.0) I have a 500 Error.
Somebody know why this happens and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to add more details.

Comment: 500 is a generic error message. Disable friendly HTTP errors and see what exact error is.

Comment: Maybe he means IIS 5 isolation mode on Win2003.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status 500 means "Internal Server Error" which would happen for a huge number of reasons (any server-side error will generally give this status).

Make sure your browser [isn't set to show Friendly Http Messages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807) and set [customErrors=false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) in your web.config (or look in the Event Viewer). You should be able to get a full exception message/stacktrace.

There are too many things that could go wrong and cause this issue depending on what your code does (do you have incorrect connection strings, paths, or other settings in your config?) for us to guess the exact cause, but if you can provide an error message and stack trace, it'll be much easier for us to help.